# Exporting VM as OVA in ESXi 6.5

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

How can I export a VM in the OVA format with VMware ESXi 6.5?

In vCenter (vSphere Client version 6.5) I can only export as an OVF. The same is true for the ESXi web client.

The old application (VMware vSphere Client 6.0 and bellow) allowed me to pick OVA, but I can't access an ESXi 6.5 host with this application. The error I get is:

> "The required client support files need to be retrieved from the server "0.0.0.0" and installed"﻿

I've tried using VMware OVF Tool to convert from OVF + VMDK to OVA without success. Is there any other solution?

Comment: I can't test it right now, but the VMware converter would be the next thing to try.

Comment: Did not work with VMware converter. I'm testing PowerCLI now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the PowerCLI cmdlet `Export-VApp`.

From [the documentation](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/PowerCLI51/html/Export-VApp.html):

> If the value of the Destination parameter is a folder, the vApp or the virtual machine is exported to a container folder (OVF). If the destination is a file, the vApp or the virtual machine is exported in OVA format.

Don't let the name fool you, it's not only for VApps.

Comment: Thank you. Using the following worked: ``Export-VApp -Destination C:\Users\...\myvm.ova -vm myvm -Format Ova``

Answer (score 1):

Try to directly copy the Virtual Machine with VHDX from old ESXi 6.5 to the ESXi 6.0 and register that on the ESXi 6.0.

Answer (score 1):

Exporting an OVF creates and downloads a bunch of files. If you have a Linux machine , you can create a tarball of the dowloaded .ovf, .vmdk and .mf files.

```
tar -cvf newvm.ova newvm.ovf newvm.vmdk newvm.mf
```

This will create a newvm.ova file which can be exported.

Note: If the VM has multiple disks, add all the downloaded .vmdk files.